# xlsxwriter conditional formatting doesn't work in loops

Tags: python-2.7, pandas, xlsxwriter

when using xslxwriter worksheet.conditional_format() the following works:

```
i = 1
worksheet.conditional_format(1,i,17,i, {'type':     'cell',
                                    'criteria': 'between',
                                    'minimum':  1,
                                    'maximum':  3,
                                    'format':   format1,
                                    })
```

But if you try to do a loop like this:

```
for i in np.arange(1,12):                               
    worksheet.conditional_format(1,i,17,i, {'type':     'cell',
                                        'criteria': 'between',
                                        'minimum':  dev1_pos,
                                        'maximum':  dev2_pos-0.01,
                                        'format':   format1_a,
                                        })
```

it says that you have an indented error

```
    worksheet.conditional_format(1,i,17,i, {'type':     'cell',
            ^
IndentationError: expected an indented block
```

Is this a bug or I'm doing it the wrong way?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try one line code, I temoved last `,` too:

```
for i in np.arange(1,12):                               
    worksheet.conditional_format(1,i,17,i, {'type': 'cell', 'criteria': 'between', 'minimum':  dev1_pos, 'maximum':  dev2_pos-0.01, 'format':   format1_a})
```

Or maybe help:

```
for i in np.arange(1,12):                               
    worksheet.conditional_format(1,i,17,i, {'type':     'cell', \
                                        'criteria': 'between', \
                                        'minimum':  dev1_pos,\
                                        'maximum':  dev2_pos-0.01, \
                                        'format':   format1_a
                                        })
```

EDIT:

I think you can check `Intendation` before `worksheet.conditional_format...`.

Comment: thanks @jezrael, but doesn't work. Tried also with and without the "," after format1_a.

Comment: same error.
 worksheet.conditional_format(1,i,17,i, {'type':     'cell','criteria': 'between','minimum':  dev1_pos,'maximum':  dev2_pos-0.01,'format':   format1_a})
            ^
IndentationError: expected an indented block

Comment: Please check `Intendation` before `worksheet.conditional_format ...` If it is correct, I remove answer, because I dont know what is problem.

Comment: actually if you keep it the way I have it, but ident twice only the first line (worksheet.cond.. etc) and keep the other lines with the original indentation it works...

Comment: Super. Hmmm, I dont know if I help you. What do you think? Can I delete answer?

Comment: it definitely helped me. Just add that to answer and I'll approve.

Answer (score 0):

The error:

```
IndentationError: expected an indented block
```

is a Python error and isn't related to XlsxWriter.

It is caused by some "indentation" issue in the program. The most common one is mixing tabs and spaces. Turn on whitespace highlighting in your editor and check that the indentation is consistent.